# Move all arguments to lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I want to create lambda that will accept any number of arguments like:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args) {
    auto l = [args...]() {
        g(args...);
    }
    // use l
}
```

Problem here is that it doesn't work with move-only types. If it was only 1 arg I would do smth like

```
void f(Arg arg) {
    auto l = [arg = std::move(arg)]() {
        g(move(arg));
    }
}
```

How to move all args to lambda?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template <class... Args>
void f(Args... args) {
  auto l = [tup=std::make_tuple(std::move(args)...)] {
    std::apply([](auto&&...args){
      g(decltype(args)(args)...);
    }, tup );
  };
}
```

A bit icky.

Pack them into a tuple, then unpack tuple with `std::apply`.  If you lack `std::apply` write yourself an equivalent one.

If you want to invoke `g` with rvalues, make outer lambda mutable, and `move` tuple into inner lambda.

Inner lambda can capture by default `&` if you want access to args of outer or the like.

We can even abstract this pattern a bit:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
auto forward_capture( F&& f, Args&&...args ) {
  return [
    f=std::forward<F>(f),
    tup=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  ]{
    return std::apply( f, tup );
  };
}
```

use:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args) {
  auto l = forward_capture(
    [](auto&&...args) {
      g(args...);
    },
    std::move(args)...
  );
  // use l
}
```

If you want the capture list first, we can do it:

```
template<class...Args>
auto forward_capture( Args&&...args ) {
  return [
    tup=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  ](auto&& f)mutable{
    return [
      f=decltype(f)(f),
      tup=std::move(tup)
    ]{
      return std::apply( f, tup );
    };
  };
}
```

use:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args) {
  auto l = forward_capture(std::move(args)...)(
    [](auto&&...args) {
      g(args...);
    }
  );
  // use l
}
```

which has the "advantage" that we have 3 nested lambdas.

Or more fun:

```
template<class...Args>
struct arrow_star {
    std::tuple<Args...> args;
    template<class F>
    auto operator->*(F&& f)&& {
      return [f=std::forward<F>(f),args=std::move(args)]()mutable{
        return std::experimental::apply( std::move(f), std::move(args) );
      };
    }
};
template<class...Args>
arrow_star<std::decay_t<Args>...> forward_capture( Args&&...args ) {
  return {std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
}
template<class...Args>
auto f(Args... args)
{
  return
    forward_capture( std::move(args)... )
    ->*
    [](auto&&...args){
      g(decltype(args)(args)...);
    };
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e8e4715bcf09d90).

Comment: @RiaD while I'm at it, here are 2 variants.  ;)

Comment: I have a question about captures with initializers. I read that they're mainly for move-only types, but couldn't the alternative to doing `[x = std::move(x)]` be to take a reference then move -> `[&]{ std::move(x); }`? Moving it in the capture list seems redundant to my untrained eyes.

Comment: @0x499 `&` has lifetime implications.